# Why is this function not replacing the class

Tags: jquery

I have a function that I'm testing, it is supposed to check all table headers to see if it has a particular class, remove it and replace it with another class.  I'm using this to switch metadata parsers for the tablesorter plugin.  The code I have so far is below:

```
$(function(){
    $("th").each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("{sorter: 'usLongDate'}")) { 
            $(this).removeClass("{sorter: 'usLongDate'}").addClass("{sorter: 'false'}");
            }       
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({}); 
});
```

I'm trying to switch the class parser in the following header to the false inline parser.

```
<th class="{sorter: 'usLongDate'}"><a rel = "Header" href="#" title="Sort column in decending order" class="">Date</a></th>
```

Of course this isn't my only header, I'm just testing it on this one, I'm assuming the rest of the headers shouldn't be affected, tablesorter should still be sorting those.  But when I run the html file, nothing works.  Is there something I'm missing?? Thanks.

NOTE: Just to avoid confusion, the tablesorter plugin for jQuery can use inline parsers within the class attribute of a table header in order to determine how and/or whether a column should be sorted.

UPDATE: Tried Vincent Robert's suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work.  In regards to whether or not addClass and removeClass can handle these.  I have an original function that was able to add the disable parser to all classes,

```
$("th[class='']").addClass("{sorter: 'false'}");
```

this comes from Paolo Bergantino, and it worked great.  I'm just trying to extend it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("th[class*='usLongDate']").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("{sorter: 'usLongDate'}").addClass("{sorter: false}");
    });
    $("table").tablesorter(); 
});
```

The issue probably stems from the fact that classes are separated by spaces.  Technically, "{sorter:" and "'usLongDate'}" are two different classes.  I don't know exactly how TableSorter is handling them, but removing "{sorter:" and then adding it back in should keep it next to "false}".

Comment: Thanks Ben, I added this with some minor adjustments and it did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong. But class="{sorter: 'usLongDate'}" is not a valid class name. Classes are names separated by spaces. class="class1 class2" means the element has two classes class1 and class2 not one class. Valid class names are explained [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-cdata).

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to change the class anyway use attr instead of add/remove class

```
$(this).attr('class', 'myNewClass');
```

and to remove use:

```
$(this).removeAttr('class');
```

Comment: Hello Nadia, yes that is my class.  Check out the tablesorter plugin for jQuery, it uses parsers within the class of a table header to determine whether or not a column should be sorted and/or how it should sort that specific column, it's pretty nifty

Comment: If you want to append the class to the already existing one. You can do something like $(this).attr('class', $(this).attr('class') + ' newclass')

Answer (score 2):

I don"t think addClass() or removeClass() can handle these kind of "classes". You should instead directly access the "class" attribute.

Now I am not familiar with this plugin...

```
$(function(){
    $("th").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "{sorter: 'usLongDate'}") { 
                $(this).attr("class", "{sorter: 'false'}");
            }           
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Just browsed the documentation and you could use the options way instead of the class way:

```
$('table').tablesorter({ 
    headers: $('th').map(function(i)
    { 
        return { sorter: false /* or whatever you want based on $(this) content */ }; 
    }) 
});
```

This should work as long as you are calling it before any tablesorter() call.

Comment: What if I want to include more than one class? e.g. have this parser separated with a space by a class that, lets say, makes the background of that column a certain color, so as an example 
class = "{sorter: 'usLongDate'} blue_bg".  Would this work for that purpose? Because that's essentially what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks.

Comment: No that won't work. attr() will just replace the whole class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Should you be calling

```
$("table").tablesorter({});
```

Before trying to look at the classes?  I'm assuming it's the plugin that is putting those class names in place ?

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, I assume if I call the tablesorter first it'll just use default sorting and ignore the inline metadata parsers.  I'll give it try.

Comment: Nah, didn't work.  Tablesorter just gets called and all other functions after are ignored.